# background image does not want to strech to full width within the section container

Tags: html, css

as you can see in my code example and the screenshot the image won't fit the container even with 100% width or whatever property I try to use. Below you can find my code

.about-us{

```
    background-image: url(images/about-us-background.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Even though I have got another section with the same code and it definitely works with the same piece of code. Here I don't see any issue but still, it is not working.[web page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO9gQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the width part as it was 100% its stretch up to container width

Example
width: 3vw; (Change according to u)

Comment: Unfortunately, vw on width does not work. I get the same result ... something other is wrong here. I'm not really sure if there is not a problem in the picture.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you should also add `background-size:cover;`

Comment: Well this solved the issue thank you.  But im not pretty sure why on my last section i didnt need to add this property and here i have to?

Answer (score 0):

you can add `background-cover : cover or 100% 100%` or `object-fit : cover` in your css